# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when using Custom User Control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I have created a custom user control (JCUserControl), and I am using it in the Main Window. And my Main Window has no codebehind.

I have this in the JCUserControl codebehind:

```
Private Sub ImmediateRadioButton_Checked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles ImmediateRadioButton.Checked
    SomeTextBox.IsEnabled = False
End Sub
```

When I run it, it fails with the NullReferenceException. If I comment out the SomeTextBox.IsEnabled = false, it runs without any problems.

Can somebody help?

Edit:

Found out that I could just check if the radio buttons are loaded before doing whatever I want to do.

Private Sub ImmediateRadioButton_Checked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles ImmediateRadioButton.Checked

If ImmediateRadioButton.IsLoaded Then
    SomeTextBox.IsEnabled = False
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it obvious? `SomeTextBox` is `null`, this is possible because not all controls can be initialized at the same time, if the `RadioButton` appears earlier in the parsing order its checked event can fire before the `TextBox` exits.

You should approach this more declarativly anyway, e.g. [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) the `TextBox.IsEnabled` to the `RadioButton.IsChecked` or add a new boolean property and bind both to that.

e.g. for the former:

```xml
<RadioButton Name="rb"/>
<!-- Apply Binding.Converter as needed, or use a DataTrigger instead -->
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb}"/>
```

Comment: I am not too sure about the part about approaching it declaratively. I am fairly new to vb.net. But how is it possible that when I have all the controls in the main window it works, but when it's in a user control it is not? thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: @will0809: May depend on how the parser handles different controls, in any case it's not something you can rely on. Read the data-binding link i provided, it's an important mechanism of WPF which usually allows you to avoid such issues altogether.